# SlideFragmentBuilder library can not use setting up a string from a Resource

Tags: android

I am trying to make an intro using custom strings (for multiple languages) using this [library](https://github.com/TangoAgency/material-intro-screen).
For example

```
  addSlide(new SlideFragmentBuilder()
            .image(R.drawable.ic_raw_logo_without_background)
            .backgroundColor(R.color.orange_tab)
            .buttonsColor(R.color.orange_intro_first)
            .title("Register!")
            .description("Have fun!")
            .build());
}
```

the .title() section when i write it like **.title(R.string.register_string)**  throws an **Error:****title(java.lang.String) in SlideFragmentBuilder cannot be applied to (int)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to load the string in the following way :
`.title(getString(R.id.register_string))`

You can read more at:

- [Android String Resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#java)

Answer (score 0):

I think that it just doesn't accept resource id for the title based off of your error.
You can still request the string resource (for multiple languages) by using~

`getString(R.string.register_string)`

This should return the resource as a string that can then be used as the title...it is kinda weird that it doesn't accept string id

Hope this helps!